# Простые типы данных в колекции Map

Tags: java, типы-данных, преобразование-типов

Читаю книгу по Java. Написано, что в коллекцию можно сохранять только объекты. Для простых типов нужно создавать класс-оболочку.

Пример:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
Double refDouble = new Double(1.24);
map.put("key",refDouble);
refDouble = (Double)map.get("key");
double d1 = refDouble.doubleValue();
```

Но без создания оболочки класса-оболочки и получения значения double из класса-оболочки все и так работает нормально. И простые типы заносятся без ошибок:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
double refDouble = 1.24;
map.put("key",refDouble);
refDouble = (Double)map.get("key");
```

Почему так? Или это просто писалось по старой версии Java?

Comment: Возможно имеется в виду при работе с генериками. Ведь общепринято писать, например `Map<String, Integer> map`.... а не просто `Map map` ибо можно будет тогда положить туда что угодно: и дабл и интежер и суслика в ананасах и носки пьяного мужа и всё это сразу...а это неправильно... А в `Map<String, Integer>` простой тип вы не воткнете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в примере Map map, и указано что просто тип нельзя засунуть, а оказалось что в даной ситуации всетаки можно.

Comment: @Yuras784, Эта цитата из книги относится к объявлению коллекции, а не к добавлению элементов в нее. Имеется ввиду, что `Map<double, double> map;` – нельзя, но `Map<Double, Double> map;` – можно. А явное отсутствие типа (как у Вас) – это очень плохая практика.

Comment: @post_zeew "Ввиду обобеностей языка, в колекцию можно сохранять только обьекты, а к ним не относятся простые типы данных, вроде int или double.Несмотря на это, вы можете добавить их в колекцию, если используете класс-оболочку для простого типа данных, Для int используйте класс Integer, для double класс Double". Написано про добавление в колекцию, а  не про обьявление колекции.

Comment: Ох, как сложно. Попробуйте перечитать ответы в этой теме. В частности про то, что явное отсутствие типа коллекции – это очень плохо.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "А в Map<String, Integer> простой тип вы не воткнете". как я понимаю int - простой тип. Но и в Вашем случает отлично заходит  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int refInt = 1;
        map.put("key",refInt);

Comment: @Yuras784, В данном примере не происходит добавление примитива. Здесь примитив сначала автоматически (*неявно*) обворачивается (упаковывается) в объектную оболочку и добавляется в коллекцию уже не примитив, а объект.

Comment: @Yuras784 имелось в виду, что например `Map<double, int>` . Будет сильно ругаться компилятор.  А при объявлении в дженерике Объекта Integer конечно можно записать 1. Integer - это ж обертка. Которая и подразумевает, что туда будут такие числа записываться

Comment: Наверняка книга писалась по версии 1.4, где ещё не было ни дженериков, ни автобоксинга. Если это так, лучше найти более современную книгу.

Comment: @Roman "Сеттер Р.В. - Изучаем Java на примерах и задачах" 2016 год.

Comment: Я более-менее внимательно пролистал эту книгу. Она действительно писалась по java 1.4, хоть там и есть несколько упоминаний о возможностях более поздних версий (в основном, во введении). `StringBuffer` вместо `StringBuilder`, никаких generics и autoboxing, в `switch` нет `String` и `enum` (о `enum` вообще ни слова), из потокобезопасности только `synchronized`, нет аннотаций, try-with-resources, лямбд и default-методов - в общем, привет из 2004 года. Стоит ли говорить, что работа примеров демонстрируется под windows xp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во втором варианте значение `double` автоматически упаковывается в оболочку `Double`.

Строки:

```
map.put("key", refDouble);
```

и

```
map.put("key", new Double(refDouble));
```

идентичны *по функционалу*, разница состоит лишь в том, что в первой строке тип `double` автоматически (*неявно*) упаковывается в оболочку `Double`, а во второй производится *явное* создание объекта типа `Double` со значением, которое имеет примитив `refDouble`.

> Несмотря на это, вы можете добавить их в коллекцию, если используете класс-оболочку для простого типа данных, для `int` используйте класс `Integer`, для `double` класс `Double`.

Тут имелось ввиду, что нельзя объявить коллекцию, параметризованную примитивным типом, но для создания такой коллекции можно воспользоваться классом оболочкой.

Например, так нельзя:

```
ArrayList<double> arrayList;
```

а вот так – можно:

```
ArrayList<Double> arrayList;
```

Comment: "Несмотря на это, вы можете добавить их в колекцию, если используете класс-оболочку для простого типа данных, Для int используйте класс Integer, для double класс Double.

Comment: Это из книги, но по сути этого не нужно делать

Comment: @Yuras784, Имелось ввиду то, что для указания типа коллекции нельзя использоваться примитивные типы. Например, вот так нельзя: `ArrayList<double> arrayList;`, но вот так `ArrayList<Double> arrayList;` – можно.

Comment: Нет. Вот переписал из книги: "Ввиду обобеностей языка, в колекцию можно сохранять только обьекты, а к ним не относятся простые типы данных, вроде int или double.Несмотря на это, вы можете добавить их в колекцию, если используете класс-оболочку для простого типа данных, Для int используйте класс Integer, для double класс Double". Но как оказалось создавать вручную класс-оболочку не нужно. Это делаеться автоматически если мы заносим в колекцию простые типы данных.

Comment: @Yuras784 `Но как оказалось создавать вручную класс-оболочку не нужно.` нужно . потому что надо использовать дженерики. А делать как вы - никто не делает. Никто не объявляет map, set, list без указания типа

Comment: @Yuras784, Как я уже писал, Ваша цитата из книги относится к объявлению коллекции. Вы объявляете коллекцию, не указывая тип, так делать крайне не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 2):

В Java Map - это обобщенный класс. Во избежания разбухания кода компилятор заменяет множество различных возможных вариаций переменных одним вариантом - Object. Парамером обобщенного класса не может быть простой тип потому, что он не является Object.  Поэтому используется автоупаковка в классы типа Integer, Double - то есть оболочки, так как они являются Object.

Comment: Если я не прав, поправьте

Comment: но без оболочки тоже работает. А пишет что не должно.

Comment: Эсли java автоматически упаковывает, тогда все понятно и создавать класс-оболочку просто избыточно. Спасибо.

Comment: Мне кажется Map<integer,double> компилятором в Map<Integer,Double> преобразовывается... В обобщенные классы пишете лучше Integer.

Comment: @user31238, `Map<integer, double>` – не скомпилируется.

Comment: У ТС компилируется

Comment: @Yuras784, У автора `Map map = new HashMap();`, а не то, что написали Вы.

Comment: Не обратил внимание

Answer (score 2):

Любой примитивный тип может быть неявно "упакован" в объект класса `Object`. Поэтому нет необходимости писать обертку для контейнера, который хранит объекты типа `Object`.

Например,

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    static void f( Object obj )
    {
        System.out.println( ( double )obj );
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        double x = 1_111.111_1;

        f( x );
    }
}
```

На консоль будет выдано

```
1111.1111
```

Что касается книги, то в книгах материал подается постепенно согласно некоторой методике, какую считает нужной избрать автор. Возможно, что он еще не писал об автоматической упаковке до этой главы.